Virtualized AMD-V/RVI is not supported on this platform
I can't start a virtual machine without an OS with “Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI” checked
I am using VMWare Workstation Pro 17.5.1, Windows 11 Pro 24H2 build 26100.2314 (was Home Single, but upgraded to Pro)
Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6 laptop, AMD Ryzen 7 5800H processor
Virtualization enabled in bios, disabled Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Sandbox, Windows Subsystem for Linux, Windows Hypervisor Platform in “optionsalfeatures”.
In the local group policy editor Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device Guard “Deploy windows application defender control” and “Turn On Virtualization Based Security” are disabled
I wrote “bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off.” in the command line running as administrator, execution was successful.
“Memory integrity” in ‘Core isolation’ is also disabled. HV Host Service, Hyper-V Data Exchange Service, Hyper-V Guest Service Interface, Hyper-V Guest Shutdown Interface, Hyper-V Heartbeat Service, Hyper-V PowerShell Direct Service, Hyper-V Remote Desktop Virtualization Service, Hyper-V Time Synchronization Service, Hyper-V Volume Shadow Copy Requestor are also disabled.
After all this, I rebooted Windows several times. somebody please tell me what I can do about this 

have you tried disabling "core isolation" in windows security?

@Bravo yes, i tried
